# Video call automatically end exactly in 60 minutes when using agora call

Tags: agora.io, videocall

I have the issue is when I create a call between 2 devices, at the 60 minutes of that call the app will crash.
I'm following the docs [agora videos call](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/landing-page?platform=iOS)  but can't find any solution for this.

Comment: for anybody who has the same issue, it is error 109 < The current token has expired. Please apply for a new token on the server and call renewToken>.
You can see it in the docs https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/error_rtc?platform=iOS

Answer (score 0):

I see Hải Trần has posted the response already in the comments.

But for anyone looking into this, you can use the delegate callback methods to be notified either when a token will expire soon, or has already expired.

This method will notify you 30 seconds before the current token expires:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Protocols/AgoraRtcEngineDelegate.html?platform=iOS#//api/name/rtcEngine:tokenPrivilegeWillExpire: